NX - Monorepo - migrating outside NX for purpose of open-sourcing non-application projects, while retaining dev experience
I've been using NX monorepo at work and for personal projects for about 2 years and I am still very happy with it.
I would soon like to release a few libraries like testing tools, templating library, some utilities for data management/transformation and Vite plugins as Open-Source projects.
It seems it is pretty problematic to have NX work for this hybrid repo model if I am not mistaken

I would still like to be able to retain the structure with libs/apps, i.e. work with every project within my single IDE Project
I would like to have separate Github project for every package, I would like that projects that aren't much connected e.g. template library vs test assertion library be in same repository, would prefer as small and focused open-source projects as possible
I want to be able to integrate changes if someone contributes without much hassle

Of course, the best thing would be solution that would allow me to retain NX, and allow me to somehow separate packages I want to open source, if anyone knows some solution I would be happy to hear it.
I have some ideas on my mind, but none are very convenient or quick to make.
